# Simplfy Excel code

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Im attempting to write up a code that is going to be applied over some old files. because the old files are all different i need the code to be semi flexible.

I have the code working i just need to simplify it a bit as it is unwieldy long. in essence the code is a simple, cell(x,y) = cell(x-1,y) + sum of 15 cells all spaced 3 columns apart. my current code is

```
ws1.Cells(n + first, 52).Formula = "=" & Split(Cells(1, 52).Address, "$")(1) & n + first - 1 & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 5).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 8).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 11).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 14).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 17).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 20).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 23).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 26).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 29).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 32).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 35).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 38).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 41).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 44).Address, "$")(1) & n + first & "+" & Split(Cells(1, 47).Address, "$")(1) & n + first
```

Im sure because it is repeated it can somehow be put input into a for loop which returns it as a string each pass through that concatenates together?

It needs to reference the cells rather than just add the cells together hence the split code to generate the column reference.

note: this is in a for loop running through values of n. First is a variable to identify the start of the calculations

Comment: Could you [Edit] your post and share the complete code along with some same data, help us to fix it!

Comment: This is a cross post of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463674/how-do-i-simplify-this